# Access ejb from web module (RESTful services) in ear application

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, ejb, ear

I have an ear application that consists of an ejb.jar and a web application (war).
The ejb.jar contains all my EJBs (beans and interfaces) and my war contains REST web services. I want to access the EJBs from the war module, is that possible? Injecting the EJBs doesn't work, I get null pointer exception.

I know that this has been asked many times but I can't seem to get this working...

I am using Glassfish v2.1.1 (I know I should upgrade, but right now it is difficult...)

Here is the code fragment that returns nullPointerException:
(I know I am not supposed to validate a user through GET, but this is just an example code I am trying just to check if I can access the ejb)

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserWS
{
    @EJB
    SB_usrRemote sb_usrRemote;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String checkLoginAttempt(String username, String password)
    {
        return sb_usrRemote.checkLoginAttempt(username, password).toString();
    }
}
```

I didn't mention that this code only works when I include the ejb.jar in the ear application's lib folder where the war module can "see" it. Is there any other way I can access the EJB classes? 
Also I am using Intellij, the application is a java EE Application that includes a web module (for the war).

**EDIT**

I couldn't avoid the glassfish upgrade from v2 to v4. It was the best decision I  made as all my problems went away. All the ejb injection in my code worked like a charm!

Thank you both for your suggestions! I am accepting hugh 's answer because JNDI probably would have worked, but upgrading glassfish seemed like a more appropriate solution in the long run.

**EDIT 2**

I finally managed to do a proper ejb injection using this code:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserWS
{
    @EJB (lookup = "java:global/<ear-name>/<ejb-jar-name>/SB_usrRemote")
    SB_usrRemote sb_usrRemote;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String checkLoginAttempt(String username, String password)
    {
        return sb_usrRemote.checkLoginAttempt(username, password).toString();
    }
}
```

I found the proper lookup path in the glassfish log when I deployed my ear file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bean isn't getting injected because this class isn't an EJB.  You should be able to get a copy using a JNDI lookup:

```
SB_usrRemote bean = (SB_usrRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("SB_usrRemote");
```

More on JNDI lookups here: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html)

Another possibility is to make the bean a managed bean - I think that's possible in JSF, but I'm afraid I don't know about that. [Edit - JAX-RS, not JSF, as per Bkail's answer]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion too, unfortunately nothing is working, I will attempt to upgrade to glassfish v3 and try again...

Comment: FWIW, Bkail's suggestion is much better.  JNDI is a valid alternative, but not as neat.  Can I ask what happens with this look-up?  If you get a `NameNotFoundException`, we can probably fix this by fiddling around with exactly what you need to look up.

Answer (score 2):

Per the JAX-RS specification, injection is not enabled by default in JAX-RS classes.  You either need to use a CDI bean deployment archive (add WEB-INF/beans.xml for CDI 1.0), make the JAX-RS class be a managed bean (add the `@ManagedBean` annotation to the class)., or make the JAX-RS class be an EJB (e.g., add the `@Stateless` annotation to the class).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I will give it a try an I will let you know!