# How to create multiple ManagedScheduledExecutorService resources in Jaxrs

Tags: jax-rs, scheduled-tasks, websphere-liberty

I'm developing a service using WebSphere Liberty (wlp) and JAX-RS. 
I want to run multiple schedulers in my service to do different tasks periodically. 
I have installed *concurrent-1.0* feature and defined an instance of

```
@Resource(name ="DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService")
private ManagedScheduledExecutorService myScheduler;
```

in my init class which implements `ServletContextListener`

How I can create some more instances in some other classes?

I can find pointers for `ManagedExecutorService` like:
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/injecting_an_executorservice_with_java
I have tried same with `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` but it didn't work.

But I'm unable to get much info for `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` resource.

Please provide any links or pointers which could be useful here.

Comment: Per the JAX-RS specification, injection is not enabled by default in JAX-RS classes.  See my answer here for additional details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31789566/142446

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injection example you have currently is making use of the Default ManagedScheduledExecutorService which is available once you turn on the `concurrent-1.0` feature.

To configure additional ManagedScheduledExecutorService's, you can simply define more in your server.xml configuration like this:

```
<managedScheduledExecutorService jndiName="concurrent/exec1"/>
<managedScheduledExecutorService jndiName="concurrent/exec2"/>
<managedScheduledExecutorService jndiName="concurrent/exec3"/>
```

However, there is really no reason you should need additional ManagedScheduledExecutorService's unless they are going to have different context service configurations applied for different tasks.  For example:

```
<managedScheduledExecutorService jndiName="concurrent/classloaderExec">
    <contextService>
        <classloaderContext/>
    </contextService>
</managedScheduledExecutorService>

<managedScheduledExecutorService jndiName="concurrent/jeeMetadataExec">
    <contextService>
        <jeeMetadataContext/>
    </contextService>
</managedScheduledExecutorService>
```

If you simply want to schedule different tasks, say `myHourlyTask` and `myDailyTask`, you can still do that with the same ManagedScheduledExecutorService resource:

```
myScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myHourlyTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
myScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myDailyTask,  0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

To declare and use `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` default resource instance in any non-resource class:

```
/** The scheduler. */
private ManagedScheduledExecutorService monkeyScheduler;
try {
        monkeyScheduler = (ManagedScheduledExecutorService) 
                new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks @aguibert for a very nice explanation. So, one resource will be able to solve the problem. But can you tell me how this resource can be declared in any other class than init class which implements ServletContextListener. Also, if it is declared there, how it be referenced in other classes without making it static.

Comment: @devesh-ahuja you can obtain the instance in any component managed by liberty (servlet, ejb, etc).  Simply perform a lookup (via `new InitialContext().lookup("concurrent/myExec")` or inject it using the `@Resource` annotation as was show in the initial question

Comment: Thanks, I used `new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService")` and it worked for me. But I was getting `NullPointerException` when I tried getting it using annotation `@Resource`. Any other thing to do with that ? I read about `@Stateless` annotation somewhere, should that be used ?

Comment: you should be able to do `@Resource ManagedScheduledExecutorService myExec;` in any container managed component (i.e. servlet, ejb, etc)

Comment: I wanted it to be in a simple java class, which is not container managed, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Check this page [Configuring managed scheduled executors](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_config_scheduledexecutor.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-2-12&lang=en) for details how to configure managed executor.

You should be able to use one executor, just call multiple `executor.schedule*` methods for your different tasks.

Comment: Thanks @Gas for the reference link. It tells about configuring a resource in `web.xml` using jndi feature. But as @aguibert mentioned, I'm using the default one `DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService`, its unable to lookup by jndi. 
I have tried both
`(ManagedScheduledExecutorService) new InitialContext().lookup("DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService");`
and 
`(ManagedScheduledExecutorService) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/concurrent/DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService");` but it gives `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:`

Comment: @devesh-ahuja you can look it up by the name defined by the Java EE7 spec which is `java:comp/DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService`.